# Target a button with its content

Tags: html, css, button

I've two buttons with same class but different content

```
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
```

I would like to change color of Sold Out button. is it possible to target a button with its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

### Updated Code;

**CASE-1 :If you want only all button to be colored**

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("a.ordrViewBtn");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Button3</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Button4</a>
```

**CASE-2 :If you want only `Sold Out` buttons to be colored**

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("a.ordrViewBtn");


for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

  if (buttons[i].innerHTML === "Sold Out") 
{
  buttons[i].style.color = "green";
  buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
}
```

```html
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
      <a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
```

Comment: Actually I've around 7 buttons
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Re-Sell</a>
<a class="button ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>

I need to change every sold buttons color, your code only changes the fist item, Right?

Comment: @VivekNathR I had updated the code , please check the answer and green tick it if this is you want

Comment: Now every buttons color changed to green, only sold out button color need to be changed

Comment: So you need the  4 `sold-out` buttons only to get changed? If YES, I had updated the code

Comment: Is it possible to change the background color with this code?

Comment: Yes but I only answered the question that you ask. For other query, create other question and send link here

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="button ordrViewBtn" id="ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>

alert($("#ordrViewBtn").text());
```

Comment: Could you please explain the above code? I didn't get that

Comment: <a class="button ordrViewBtn" id="ordrViewBtn">Sold Out</a>  <script>
 alert($("#ordrViewBtn").text());
</script>   you can able to get the Sold Out as value and using css change the color of button